# Qual a diferença entre usar o input() e usar o sys.stdin.readline()?

Tags: python, input

Qual a diferença entre usar o `input()` e usar `sys.stdin.readline()`?

Comment: Além das diferenças já citadas na resposta abaixo, também há diferença quando ocorre um EOF (por exemplo, quando você digita Ctrl-D no Linux): `input` lança um [`EOFError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#EOFError), enquanto `sys.stdin.readline()` retorna a string vazia.

Answer (score 3):

Direto da boca do cavalo:

```
>>> input()
bla
'bla'
>>> input("digite algo: ")
digite algo: bla
'bla'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.readline()
bla
'bla\n'
>>> sys.stdin.readline(5)
blaaaaaaaaaaaa
'blaaa'
```

Como se vê, input() não inclui o caractere de fim de linha, enquanto o outro inclui. readline() aceita um parâmetro opcional que é o tamanho máximo da string a ser retornada.

Me parece que input() é mais apropriado para interação com humano enquanto readline() é mais voltado quando o programa será parte de um pipe.

Comment: Outra diferença é que `input` aceita como parâmetro uma string que é exibida antes de pedir a entrada dos dados

Comment: @hkotsubo adicionei este caso no exemplo, vlw